# How to store command output in file

Tags: python, operating-system

I need to store output of a system command in a text file.

eg:-

```
import os
os.system('ls -al')
```

Its output :

```
drwx------  2 root root  4096 Aug  7 12:08 .ssh
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 27  2021 Templates
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    63 Aug 11 20:29 txt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Oct 24 07:03 Videos
-rw-------  1 root root  6813 Jul 25 07:43 .viminfo
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Mar  1  2021 .vscode
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Aug  9 10:19 .wpscan
-rw-------  1 root root    98 Oct 24 16:13 .Xauthority
-rw-------  1 root root 27650 Oct 24 18:12 .xsession-errors
-rw-------  1 root root 40368 Oct 24 12:32 .xsession-errors.old
-rw-------  1 root root 24328 Oct 24 17:07 .zsh_history
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  8238 Feb 27  2021 .zshrc
```

I need to store this output data in a text file. Please help me.

Comment: Nice question ID!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `>` to write the command line output to a file as follows:

```
import os
os.system('ls -al > output.txt')
```

Comment: For reference, `>>` means append

Answer (score 1):

`os.system("ls -al")` won't return the output you normally see in the shell but only the return code. `0` if the command was executed successfully, `1` if not, etc. Read more about this [here](https://shapeshed.com/unix-exit-codes/).

But you can use `subprocess.check_output()`to do so.
Be aware, that the command must be passed to the method as a list of commands / parameters:

```py
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(["ls", "-al"])
open("output.txt", "w").write(output)
```